# Null value passed in Safari to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, safari, null

We have a C#.NET MVC 4 application with MVVM on the client side. When performing a particular action in the application the parameters in the client that are going to be passed to the webAPI are OK but once in the webAPI the controller receives a null parameter instead so it gives an error.
   This happens only the first time we perform the action, the second time works fine and this ONLY happens when running the application on Apple Safari (it works fine in Microsoft Internet Explorer, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox).
   Any ideas?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this??